# Unity Bug Reporter after working on animation and ragdoll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So this is the way the story goes. I was working on a new human model, which had improved weight painting and came with some animations (the old model had none). What I did was I put them all in an animator attached to my humanrigrough gameobject (in the animation controller, obviously). I think the reason I got crashed is that it might have tried to do two animations at once but I'm not sure. The other thing is, I was making a ragdoll for the new model and copy-pasting all the values for the rigidbody, character joint, and collider from the old model to the new model. I don't think anything went wrong here since it worked just fine with the old model, and it's not like it would make this much of an error even if all the values were wrong, but I don't know. The last two things were the human script I attached to the new model (copy-pasted values, once again) (this script controls the animator parameters) and navmesh (copy-pasted also). I also had a script on my pelvis object that controls when the ragdoll is active (which is when the human dies).

**My question is what is going on and how do I fix it?**

If you need any more information, I'll do my best to give it with the limitation that Unity is crashing. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this because the project is very important to me.

UPDATE: I made a copy of the project and was able to open an empty scene on it, but accessing my main scene and any duplicates crashed Unity. I also deleted all prefabs, materials, animations, scripts, etc. from the project, but still had no luck opening the scene...

Comment: No idea. Report it to unity

Comment: Wow, that sounds really complicated! Think you're going to have to isolte all the operations one at a time and see which is crashing. Otherwise is there a simpler way to do what you want?

Comment: You mean delete the script components and see if unity will run again?

Comment: Hi, this sounds like it is a compatibility issue between the new version of Unity and the old version of Unity. You can go to Unity's official website for corresponding help. https://forum.unity.com/